# Qt for UI and Kotlin for application logic

Tags: qt, kotlin, zeromq

I would like to use Kotlin for Linux desktop application. It does not have good UI library. I decided Qt would work well. So I though I would combine those two together. I do not want to use bindings library since there seams to not be any stable and maintained language binding. The way I would like to bind those two would be through use of ZeroMQ. I would like to have two way communication with application (UI needs to react to back end events too).

Has anyone tried such architecture or similar? Will there be any problem like validation or not being able to bind to the data. I would like to minimize use of C++, and use Kotlin for application logic, database, http communication with web server.

I am looking to build medium complexity embedded touch based interface (buttons, text fields, data rows).

Has anyone tried that? Is there a design error?

Communication between ZeroMQ and UI would resemble EventBus pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *Has anyone tried such architecture or similar?*

Yes.

> **Q** : *Is there a design error?*

No.

Given you run for right-sized problem approach, the best production-grade results are expected from extending the industry-proved ( since adopted as early as in PARCplace Systems SmallTalk evangelisation in early 1980-ies... indeed some time to prove it be valid and best in class, isn't it? ) **M**odel-**V**isual-**C**ontroller.

Have implemented the MVC-architecture-pattern in a shape and form of a [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system), integrated atop the smart ZeroMQ communcation infrastructure. Remote-keyboard was one of remote'd **C**-controller-inputs (with a dumb CLI **V**-isual ), another host ( supported by a computing grid ) did consolidate and operate the global **M**-odel and all the MVC-state transitions, next using another remote **V**-isual platform, for GUI and some other MMI-interactions, recollected from there back, into the central **M**-odel part.

Indeed a lovely way to design whatever complex systems!

It was robust, smart, scalable and maintainable architecture and would but recommend to follow this path forwards.

Comment: Very high level answer. I think I will go with gRPC as it has bidirectional streaming feature. I expect it will simplify the stack while being interoperable.

Comment: Bear with me please, but isn't this architecture called N-Tier ?